# A text import screen pops up while trying to copy and paste an xlsx spreadsheet

Tags: libreoffice, copy-and-paste

When I try to copy and paste an xlxs spreadsheet, a text import screen pops up. This has not happened before.

How do I stop it and, revert back to a simply copy and paste?

Comment: Please provide more details, what OS/release, what software are you talking about (a file browser such as `nautilus`, inside a something like LibreOffice Calc or what program)

Comment: please look at [ask] and [edit] your question with additional details about which version of Ubuntu you are using and where you are pasting the xlx spreadsheet to.